# How to reformat Javascript file in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) for my web development and missing the feature of javascript reformat code. It seems to be not working at all for javascript however working for Java and HTML files.
Is there any free plugin or some other way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: This feature is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate only, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html.

Comment: Web technologies are not supported in Community Edition. They are only supported in Ultimate and WebStorm.

Comment: Any workaround for that? I don't want to switch to eclipse in the middle of the project.

Comment: You can use external formatters via plug-ins like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-adapter-for-eclipse-code-formatter.

Comment: @CrazyCoder A plugin that you share is only for the Java code and not for the Javascript.